# Picker Not Showing?

Tags: iphone

When I drag `PickerView` on my window as my program runs, it's not showing any `PickerView`? Please guide me. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You should try taking a screenshot of the IB design after dragging the PickerView and provide more information about constraints, frame of the PickerView with reference to the screenshot. That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are new to iPhone programming so, a million of things could be happening. 
Just some guesses/advices:

1. Make sure the view you are seeing when you run the program and when editing it in Interface Builder is the same.(If you are not sure, change the background color of the view so you will know, etc.)
2. Make sure you did save the file (in interface builder) before compiling.
3. In Xcode, Clear all and Build again ;)

Comment: thx , but this Happen just for PickerView and Table , other Component show.Buttons , lables , progress all having work good.just for pickerview have problem.

Comment: hummm... maybe the picker is behind other view? or its coodinates (frame) is out of the screen? Is estrange. There should be no problem. ;(